# How to write a pandas dataframe with a datetime variable name

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am scheduling a python script to run everyday,which outputs a dataframe. I wish to save the dataframe everyday with that day's date. For example for today it would be '12/11/18.csv'

How can i write such a csv file?

I'm doing `df.to_csv('datetime.datetime.today().strftime.csv')` but as expected it is saving it with the filename 'datetime.datetime.today().strftime.csv' not today's date as such

Comment: Having `/` in file names is not a good idea if you want those files to be portable.

Comment: Not to mention that Y-m-d is a much better format for ordering files since the OS then has a hope of chronological ordering when viewing the folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df.to_csv(f'{today}.csv')
```

This works too:

```
df.to_csv(f'{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}.csv')
```

In the `strftime` function you can mention the format you like.

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.datetime.today().strftime` is a function.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.today().strftime                                                                                 
<function datetime.strftime>
```

You need to call it with a format specifier.

Since having `/` in file names is not a good idea for portability, I suggest

```
>>> datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%F')                                                                           
'2018-12-11'
```

which you can then format with

```
>>> '{}.csv'.format(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%F'))                                                          
'2018-12-11.csv'
```

Comment: To be honest I didn't know about `%F`. How come it is not documented (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)?

Comment: @DeepSpace good question! I learned this specifier as a shortcut for `'%Y-%m-%d'` from a pandas book (Python for Data Analysis) recently, I did not know it's missing in the documentation.

Comment: Doh, sorry, for some reason I thought you were calling strftime on the output of `pd.to_datetime('today')`.... (you know, since this was tagged pandas). My bad!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_csv('%s.csv' % datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

You can change **-** with **/**, but it's quite dirty to have those in file name.